# AWS ElasticBeanstalk boto3 - how to select capacity when creating environment?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Boto3 I can create environment programmatically:

```
env_result = client.create_environment(
                ApplicationName = aws_application_name,
                EnvironmentName = env_name,
                CNAMEPrefix = env_name,
                SolutionStackName = '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.3 running Python 3.6',
                OptionSettings = [
                    {
                        'Namespace': 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
                        'OptionName': 'IamInstanceProfile',
                        'Value': 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role'
                    }
                ]
            )
```

But as result, the application capacity is set as "Load balanced" whereas I want it to be a "Single instance".

I think option settings are probably wrong but I can't figure out what it should be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. I had to add another OptionsSettings object:

```
                {

                    'Namespace': 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment',
                    'OptionName': 'EnvironmentType',
                    'Value': 'SingleInstance'
                }
```